# Using Webpack Dev Server Behind a proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have a nginx proxy which proxies all requests on dev.local/myapp to localhost:3000. Port 3000 is mapped to port 80 within my docker machine, which is running webpack-dev-server with hot reload.

The webpack-dev-server has to serve eveything from / but all requests have to go against dev.local/myapp to the proxy correctly forwards it to my webpack-dev-server.

But currently the hot reloader always goes against dev.local/sockjs-node and not dev.local/myapp/sockjs-node

How do I have to configure webpack correctly?

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    paths.appIndexJs
  ],
  output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://dev.local/myapp'
  }, ...
```

Comment: Have a look at my [answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256044/webpack-development-server-seperate-subdomain-proxied-by-nginx/50162649#50162649). Looks like its the same.